# puppet compilation build command failing

Tags: puppet

The solution below solved one problem but another has popped up:

Here is the code:

```
exec { "Download Phalcon":
    path => ["/usr/bin/", "/home/cphalcon/build"],
    command => "git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git /home/cphalcon",
    require => [Package["git"], Package["php5-fpm"]]
}

exec { "Build Phalcon":
    require => Exec["Download Phalcon"],
    command => "./install",
#    creates => "/home/cphalcon/build",
    cwd => "/home/cphalcon/build",
    path => ["/usr/bin", "/home/cphalcon/build"]
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
==> default: Error: ./install: line 38: rm: command not found
==> default: ./install: line 64: phpize: command not found
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[Build Phalcon]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: ./install: line 38: rm: command not found
==> default: ./install: line 64: phpize: command not found
```

Any ideas? phpize is not missing when I manually invoke ./install from the CLI - why would it be missing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` command does not work that way when it comes to the `cwd` parameter. It sets the current directory, but does not allow commands to be ran relative to that directory.

You need to also set the `path` parameter (so `path => ['/home/cphalcon/build']` in your case). Take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-command)

Comment: Your comment did the trick but I have another related issue which I am not sure how to solve - edited the original question :)